# Jenkins failed to launch the slave agent

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent

I am trying to launch new slave agent but I am seeing the below error. Can you please help in resolving this.

- I have copied the keys in both the machines in `.ssh/authorized_keys` and able to connect manually but failing from Jenkins.
- All permissions also looks good.

```
    [02/19/16 13:12:34] [SSH] Opening SSH connection to sdc-caoneops-    app1.qa.xxxxx.com:22.
    ERROR: Server rejected the 1 private key(s) for App (credentialId:6aced962-  26cd-4c8f-97d3-305c2e2a6540/method:publickey)
    [02/19/16 13:12:34] [SSH] Authentication failed.
    hudson.AbortException: Authentication failed.
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.openConnection(SSHLauncher.java:1178)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:701)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:696)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    [02/19/16 13:12:34] Launch failed - cleaning up connection
    [02/19/16 13:12:34] [SSH] Connection closed.
```

Answer (score 0):

When you ssh manually from master to slave, you are doing so as the Jenkins master user, right? You only need to copy the public key from the master into ~/.ssh/authorized_keys of the slaves.

- Add Jenkins Credentials for the jenkins private key and you use that pair in slave configuration **"Credentials"**.
- In slave configuration add in **"Remote root directory"** the home directory of jenkins user on the slave (which contains .ssh/authorized_keys)